# How to handle a form from another controller in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have 2 separate controllers `Controller1:somethingAction` and `Controller2:processForm`.

In `somethingAction` I create a form and set its action (url) to `processForm`'s url. When the form in `somethingAction`'s view is submitted, POST data goes to `processForm`.

In `processForm`, I create the same form, validate it and process it. Everything works excellent, except when the form is invalid. Because in order to show errors as well as entered data by user,  you would need to render exactly the same view as `somethingAction`.

It bums me out that I can't reuse forms like this without copying code (the process form part), even if it's 3-4 lines, I would expect to have this kind of functionality.

Is there a simple way to do it? Without AJAX. Am I missing something?

It could be done if embedding controllers could redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might help:

1) Scroll down to 'Creating form classes' in the docs for how to avoid duplicating your form:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

2) A common pattern (I would say better in many cases) is to post to the same controller action that generates the form initially. That is, `Controller1:somethingAction` POSTs to `Controller1:somethingAction`. You then need some logic (basically an IF statement) that detects when the form has been submitted and either process the form, or display it with errors. In pseudo code it could look like:

```
function somethingAction()
    if form.isValid()
        process form
        redirect or render a success screen
    else
        render form (with or without errors)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. My forms are classes that are tied to entities. I'm not duplicating any form. It's the process part code that is being duplicated.

Comment: No worries, wasn't quite sure from your question. Ignore (1), give (2) a try. Works for me anyway. I can put in some actual PHP code if it helps at all.

Comment: No sweat. I believe what I have is exactly as (2). Create form, if request method is POST then process form, then create view. It works wonders if you don't plan to use that form in more than 1 place.

Comment: If your process logic is more than a couple of lines you might want to write it out into a separate class, you can just point to that code each time you need to process. You could even set it up as a service. Or a quick + cheerful way in PHP 5.4 might be to create a `trait` you can `use` with each controller.